# Joomla Ignite Gallery Doesn't display Alt tags

Tags: joomla, gallery

Today is the first day I am looking to the Joomla website.
I had to do very simple thing - add Alt text to images.

I spend many hours of research... at the end I have found the following:

- website is using Joomla 2.5.7
- there is Ignite Gallery installed and it is used for images uploading
- afterwards I see that images appears using fancybox
- also I do see that application doesn't display original images, but resized ones
- I have changed Alt tags for images in Ignite Gallery and published everything
- also I have cleared all browser cache to be sure that this is not a cache thing
- I have tried to unpublish image and this works fine (images is not displayed anymore) and then publish again (fine), but no alt tags
- and the last: I do see that alt tag in database column alt_text

I do not have any result. Alt text do not appear anywhere on the page. Alt value is always empty for all images.
No Alt tags, but there should be some.

As this is my first day and night with Joomla and Ignite Gallery I have found very much, however, it is not enough and I am stuck here.

Can you give me some hint were to look at...
I need alt text for images for better SEO.

Comment: Did you check images thumbnails?

Answer (score 0):

This was caused by some developer custom changes. I have fixed them. default_menu & default_main files for component where fixed, adding $row->alt_text.